# How do you pass in parameters to the Inno Setup command line compiler?

Tags: inno-setup

It was suggested in the IS newsgroup to use /D= but using the iscc.exe that came with version 5.2.3 I get an "Unknown option:" error.

Then in the script, how do you use the value of the command line parameter?

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. All were helpful. I hate to pick out just one as the preferred answer.

Answer (score 25):

You do, as MicSim says, need the preprocessor.  It's included in the latest ISPack.  Once it's installed, iscc supports /D.

You can then use the values defined like this (assuming you'd done /DVERSION_NAME=1.23):

```
AppVerName=MyApplication v{#VERSION_NAME}
```

Comment: This is built-in to Inno Setup 5 now, so you don't have to download any extra packs.

Comment: This is not part of the documentation. Please include some helpful info here: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline

Answer (score 5):

From the Inno Setup helpfile:

> Inno Setup Preprocessor replaces the
>   standard Inno Setup Command Line
>   Compiler (ISCC.exe) by an extended
>   version. This extended version
>   provides extra parameters to control
>   Inno Setup Preprocessor.

The "extra parameters" include the /d option.

Comment: Helpful to know, but `ISPP` is a `DLL`, not an `EXE`, so not sure how you can run that from the commandline.

Comment: The answer is in the Inno documentation. Check out the section titled "Inno Setup Preprocessor: Command Line Compiler Execution". In short, /Dname=value defines a parameter that's made available to the preprocessor.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll have to look into this a little more. Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 0):

The point of the answer by `@Steven Dunn` is to solve the problem with another layer of abstraction: instead of calling `iscc your_script.iss` directly from the terminal, call `your_script.ps1 -YourVar "value"`, process the switch, write a `#define` to the `.iss` file, and *then* compile it with `iscc`. This was not articulated well and I don't think the function shown to parse command line arguments added much value. However, I'm giving credit where credit is due.

As `@jdigital` mentioned, `ISPP` has the `/d` switch, but `ISPP` can't be run directly from the terminal (AFAIK). Hence, something like a secondary scripted approach hinted at by `@Steven Dunn` is necessary.

You can achieve this by adding placeholders to an existing `.iss` script and then overwrite them accordingly:

##### `.iss` Template

```
; -- template.iss --

#define MyVar ""

...
```

##### `.ps1` Script

```
#requires -PSEdition Core

# create_iss_script.ps1

param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$MyVar,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$OutFile,
)

$File = '.\template.iss'
$LineToReplace = '#define MyVar ""'
$NewLine = "#define MyVar ""${MyVar}"""

$FileContent = Get-Content -Path $File -Raw

$FileContent.Replace($LineToReplace, $NewLine) | Set-Content -Path $OutFile
```

##### Example Terminal Usage

```
PS> .\create_iss_script.ps1 -MyVar "HelloWorld!" -OutFile "helloworld.iss"
PS> iscc .\helloworld.iss
```

or run the `iscc` step from within your `.ps1` script, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

The `/D` command line arg worked great for me. If you are struggling with the syntax I recommend just invoking `iscc \?` to see the help menu since it is pretty useful here.

Here is how we create our installer:

```
$ISCC = 'path/to/iscc.exe'
$ExternalDependency = 'random/path/to/external/dep'
# Make sure to quote escape /D filepath params
Start-Process -FilePath $ISCC -ArgumentList "/D""DepDir=$ExternalDependency"" VersionNo=1.1.0 ./myscript.iss""" -NoNewWindow
```

Then within the ISS you access like any other var:

```
[Setup]
AppVersion={#VersionNo}

[Files]
Source: "{#DepDir}\*"; DestDir: "{app}\external\";
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to parse command line arguments from code in inno, then use a method similar to this. Just call the inno script from the command line as follows:

```
C:\MyInstallDirectory>MyInnoSetup.exe -myParam parameterValue
```

Then you can call the GetCommandLineParam like this wherever you need it:

```
myVariable := GetCommandLineParam('-myParam');
```

//==================================================================

```
{ Allows for standard command line parsing assuming a key/value organization }
function GetCommandlineParam (inParam: String):String;
var
  LoopVar : Integer;
  BreakLoop : Boolean;
begin
  { Init the variable to known values }
  LoopVar :=0;
  Result := '';
  BreakLoop := False;

  { Loop through the passed in arry to find the parameter }
  while ( (LoopVar < ParamCount) and
          (not BreakLoop) ) do
  begin
    { Determine if the looked for parameter is the next value }
    if ( (ParamStr(LoopVar) = inParam) and
         ( (LoopVar+1) < ParamCount )) then
    begin
      { Set the return result equal to the next command line parameter }
      Result := ParamStr(LoopVar+1);

      { Break the loop }
      BreakLoop := True;
    end

    { Increment the loop variable }
    LoopVar := LoopVar + 1;
  end;
end;
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: your answer is stating a different thing of what's asked here... the OP wants to pass parameters to the command line compiler, not to the installer itself.

Comment: Please delete this answer - it adds confusion and is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Yes it is differents, but this answers to my problems. So thanks

Comment: I knew someone would give this answer - not related to the question but helped me. Thanks :)