# How can I customize the INNO template.iss file to be used in a JavaFX 8 build

Tags: maven, javafx-8, inno-setup

I would like to pass the maven version number of the project to the native installer process.  I know I can use the 0.0.1 tag during the build, however this seems to only work when I don't have a customized *.iss file in my project.

I need to change the defaults to place the application in the program files, and change the silent run options.  Currently I have that in a custom *.iss file which my build finds and uses.  I can't seem to get the number passed through.

So I am wondering how to **modify the template.iss** so that I can create my defaults and then let it dynamically generate from there.

We can't provide the version number when using a customized ISS file, therefore I would like to change the template.iss file that is used during the packaging - but I am unsure how to change it.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters from Java FX Ant task to Inno Setup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374416/how-to-pass-parameters-from-java-fx-ant-task-to-inno-setup)

Comment: Thanks for you post, however this is not a duplicate of that post.  I am trying to use a customized ISS file for inno.  My version number is passed at generation time - however when I use a preconfigured file in my project, I can't pass the version number there.  I want to know how to override the template.iss file which is used in the processing.  Thanks

Comment: So you can generate the template from the numbers, right?

Comment: Yes - when I run the INNO process (using the zenjava plugin) if I don't provide a customized application.iss, it will generate one during the run using the nativeReleaseVersion property.  However I lose the other information like {pf}/foldername for the install directory (template.iss uses the user AppLocal.  So if I could change them template.iss, then I could set up my defaults, and then allow the dynamic stuff to come through.

Comment: I do not know what zenjava is. But in JavaFX, the only solution is to edit the `template.iss`. So either modify it as part of the build. Or modify it upfront to use environment variables for the version and set the variables during the build.

Comment: That is my question - I can't seem to find how/where to modify that template.  Thanks

Comment: @ Martin Prikryl - do you have a sample of how to modify the template.iss?

Comment: No I do not have any sample.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl the javafx-maven-plugin was created by Daniel Zwolenski who had a website called "ZenJava". That [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin) is now maintained by me, used by some people who want to create native bundles via maven.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jdk8, you can edit the template.iss in the following ways. (other jdk versions can use similar solutions)

The `template.iss` file location is `com\oracle\tools\packager\windows\template.iss` in jar `%JAVA_HOME%\lib\ant-javafx.jar`. You can edit this jar file use WinRAR(or other compression tools), update it's contents.

This solution seems ugly, not portable, but it works.

I know this is an old question, and I hope can help others.