# How can I pass command line parameters with a value to the Inno Setup Compiler, so I can use them in my code?

Tags: command-line, parameters, inno-setup

I have two possible build options. As I don't want my clients to start the installer with some parameters, I'd better pass them to the compiler and do all the job in my code.

Let's say I have the variable `UNION` which may take two values: `0` and `1`. I have to analyze the value of that variable in my code and depending on the result to include some files or not.
I know how to pass parameterrs to the installer itself, but how can I pass them to the compiler?

Here's some code:

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  Code: Integer;
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
    begin
      if not IsUnion then
        begin
          DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{app}')+'\Locale\C4Union.UKR');
          DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{app}')+'\Locale\C4Union.ENU');  
        end;
    end;
end;
```

`IsUnion` is the function that should analyze the parameter taken from the command line and then do its job depending on the result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you pass in parameters to the Inno Setup command line compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512706/how-do-you-pass-in-parameters-to-the-inno-setup-command-line-compiler)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compiler (or technically the [preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/)) has [`/D` command-line switch](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=isppcc), which you can use to set a preprocessor variable.

For example this...

```
ISCC.exe Example1.iss /DBinaryName=MyProg.exe
```

... has the the same effect, as if you use [`#define` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=define) in the script itself, like this:

```
#define BinaryName "MyProg.exe"
```

So you can use it the same way in the script:

```
[Files]
Source: "{#BinaryName}"; DestDir: "{app}"
```

---

You can use a variable even in [conditions](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=if) like:

```
ISCC.exe Example1.iss /DMode=Install
```

```
#if Mode == "Install"
[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
#elif Mode == "Delete"
[InstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{app}\MyProg.exe"
#else
#error Unknown mode
#endif
```

---

Though for the same effect you can use just a [variable existence](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=if), like:

```
ISCC.exe Example1.iss /DInstall /DDelete
```

```
#ifdef Install
[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
#endif

#ifdef Delete
[InstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{app}\MyProg.exe"
#endif
```

This is also covered in these questions:

- [How do I build two different installers from the same script in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3034747/850848)
- [Compile Inno Setup installer for specific component only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48500040/850848)

---

You can use the preprocessor directives anywhere, even in the `[Code]` section.

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    #ifdef Delete
    DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{app}')+'\Locale\C4Union.UKR');
    DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{app}')+'\Locale\C4Union.ENU');  
    #endif
  end;
end;
```

or even:

```pascal
#ifdef Delete
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{app}')+'\Locale\C4Union.UKR');
    DeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{app}')+'\Locale\C4Union.ENU');  
  end;
end;
#endif
```

---

The preprocesor does not care, it kicks in as the very first step and treats the `.iss` file as a plain text file. Pretty much like [C/C++ preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). It does not care (much) about the sections or code structure. You can even do things like:

```
DeleteFile(
  ExpandConstant(
    #ifdef DeleteFromUserData
    '{userappdata}\MyProg'
    #else
    '{app}'
    #endif
    )+'\Locale\C4Union.UKR');
```

---

*[Add `SaveToFile` to the end of the script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3328375/850848) to see the generated code.*

Comment: Well, that's new to me! Didn't know that! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking more comfortable solution see this extension for Visual Studio:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=unSignedsro.VisualInstaller

You can easily set multiple symbols/configurations in Project Properties [image: Project Properties] and build your installers with various configurations/outputs etc.

(Feel free to contact me if you have any questions, I am author of this extension).