Innosetup - "if" based on passed parameter
I'm running my setup.iss file via Powershell script:
if ($something -eq 'test') {
    $usePort= 1
}

if ($something -ne 'dev') {
    $usePort= 0
}

& $innoiscc ".\setup.iss" /DUSEPORT="$usePort" 

In my setup.iss I want to use that USEPORT to determine if I need to add a next step:
#ifndef USEPORT
  #define USEPORT "0"
#endif

(... not relatable code)

if (#USEPORT = "1") then
  begin
    do_something
  end;

The lines with #ifndef are just to be sure that every time USEPORT will have any value, since from .ps1 file it's also possible that USEPORT won't be even declared.
I'm constantly getting an error 'Char error' on line
if (#USEPORT = "1") then

I have also tried:
if (#USEPORT = 1) then
if (#USEPORT == 1) then
if (#USEPORT == "1") then

With the same result, and error pointing to the same line.
When I've tried to delete that # char, like this:
if (USEPORT = 1) then
if (USEPORT == 1) then
if (USEPORT == "1") then

I'm getting error

Unknown identifier 'USEPORT'

What is wrong?

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/60888905/850848

Use #if..#endif instead of if, eg:
#ifndef USEPORT
  #define USEPORT "0"
#endif

(... not relatable code)

#if (USEPORT == "1")
do_something
#endif

